# React Environmental Variables are undefined with Dotenv

Tags: reactjs, webpack, axios, dotenv

I am using dotenv to create an environment variable to insert a base url into my API call using react, dotenv, and webpack.

When I call the variables in the code, I don't get any error other than them printing as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my webpack file

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv(),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: "process/browser",
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
     })
    ],
  };
};
```

Here are what the variables look like in the .env file in the root of my project

```
API_URL=http://localhost:8000
BASE_URL=https://my-url.com
```

And here is how I am accessing it in the code (with axios for auth)

```
  axiosAuth: axios.create({
    baseURL: `${process.env.BASE_URL}`,
    timeout: 5000,
  })
```

Comment: REACT_APP_BASE_URL 
just name like this. 
every time you set a .env variable start it with REACT_APP_YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME 
It might help

Answer (score 2):

Like Shah already explain, the only thing that you need is add the prefix "REACT_APP" to your current variables..
Change this:

```
API_URL=http://localhost:8000
BASE_URL=https://my-url.com
```

To this:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://my-url.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the values explicitly to be defined instead of the whole `process.env`. Try:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'process.env': {
       API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
       BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_URL),
    }
})
```

And if you're using create-react-app, prefixing `REACT_APP_` will also work and you could remove the define plugin and Dotenv.

example:

`API_URL -> REACT_APP_API_URL // .env`

usage: `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL